# Visual studio embedded web server bind ip address

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio-2008

By default, the embedded web server of VS 2008 starts on address 127.0.0.1. Due to some complex network configure issue, I have to start the web server on the IP of host(i.e. 10.46.30.240).

What I want to know is if this is possible with VS2008 configuration, Or I have to do some Windows 2003 hacking to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using windows 2003, why not just start a real instance of a web server and just attach to the w3wp.exe process ? This way you can do any configuration you want to the web server and bypass visual studio's internal web server process

Comment: Actually, this is the first thing I did. But I am too stupid to configure iis to allow debugging. All I get is the "process does not allow debug" message when I try to attach to w3wp.exe.

Comment: see this thread..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288739/cannot-remote-debug-iis-w3wp-exe-is-grayed-out